# Two if-test conditions on Excel Sheet, using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, if-statement, xlrd

I'm extracting data from an Excel file using the following code:

```
for row in range(sheet.nrows):                      # For-loop, for all rows
                 for col in range(sheet.ncols):     # For-loop, for all columns
                    if((re.match(r'F\d-\w*',str(sheet.cell(row,col).value))) and str(sheet.cell(row+2,col).value)!=None):            # If cell starts with F(number)-(several word chars) AND if cell two rows below this is not empty
                        works2.write(num_row+1,num_col,(sheet.cell(row,col)).value)     
                        works2.write(num_row, num_col,(sheet.cell(row-2,col)).value
    ect...
```

**This code worked nicely until I added the second condition to the if test**. I don't want the code to read in anything for columns where there is no data, i.e. the second if-test condition. Currently, however, the second if-test does nothing and I'm still reading in a few empty columns of data. Can someone help me spot my error/possibly re-phrase my second if test so that it checks if the cell 2 rows below the cell (row, col) is empty and only enters the commands under the if-test if it is not?

Apologies for asking such a basic question. I just can't seem to get this to do what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second condition is wrong, you are actually doing -

```
str(sheet.cell(row+2,col).value)!=None)
```

You are converting the result of `sheet.cell(row+2,col).value` to string, if its `None` the result of `str(sheet.cell(row+2,col).value)` would be the string `'None'` and this would never be equal to `None` , you would never get a `None` output from `str()` . And that is why its behaving as if the condition was never there.

You should try -

```
if (re.match(r'F\d-\w*',str(sheet.cell(row,col).value))) and sheet.cell(row+2,col).value not in [None, '']:
```

In this new condition, it would correctly work for both `sheet.cell(row+2,col).value` being `None` .

Comment: This is a very good answer, however I want the last statement to be true if the cell contains the number 0, which it is currently not. Any idea how I can modify it?

Comment: Unfortunately, that appears to make it do nothing again:
                    if((re.match(r'F\d-\w*',str(sheet.cell(row,col).value))) and (sheet.cell(row+2,col).value is not None)):
Alternatively I think I could test if sheet.cell(row+2,col).value contains a number or sheet.cell(row+1,col).value contains 'Error'. I've tried to do the latter but was unsuccessful. Any more thoughts?

Comment: How about trying to latest? Maybe `.value` is empty string, and not None.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by that? I've tried to set the second condition !=' ' and ='\d*' (0-several numbers) but these don't work. The latter gives me a syntax error and marks the = sign

Comment: The latest condition, I changed it a bit